# Database design for user roles with dependencies

Tags: mysql, authentication, database-design, roles

I have a users table, and each user can have one or more roles (from a total of about five). Depending on the roles, the user will have associations with other tables. For example a trader will have an "account", a manager will have a "company" etc.

How can I model this please?

Comment: why don't you use a database with built-in users and roles?

Comment: Neil - I do not understand.

Comment: I'm suggesting you could use built-in database roles and security instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I have no idea what Neil is talking about but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425711/preferred-database-design-method-for-assigning-user-roles-hats-vs-groups?rq=1) sounds like yours and it has a good answer.